# Correct way to construct SQLite query with varying amount of filter parameters

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm learnig how to work with SQLite in Python 3. I am using this example code:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("create table people (city, name_last, age)")

where = "Moscow"
who = "Yeltsin"
age = 72

cur.execute("insert into people values (?, ?, ?)", (where, who, age))

con.close()
```

Let's assume I have multiple rows in my database with different names, ages, cities. For the sake of this test I did this by hand. This is my function to query my data:

```
def query_db(param1, param2, param3):
    con = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM people WHERE (city == ? AND name_last == ? AND age == ?)", (param1, param2, param3))
    return(cur.fetchall())

print(query_db("Moscow", "Yeltsin", 72))
```

I would now like to change this function in a way that it works when only one or two params are set, allowing a user to basically filter by one, two or three parameters regardless. My initial approach was to construct the query command by adding strings like this:

```
def query_db(param1='', param2='', param3=''):
    con = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    if param1 != '':
        if param2 != '':
            if param3 != '':
                cur.execute("SELECT * FROM people WHERE (city == ? AND name_last == ? AND age == ?)", (param1, param2, param3))
            else:
                cur.execute("SELECT * FROM people WHERE (city == ? AND name_last == ?)", (param1, param2))
        else:
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM people WHERE city == ?", (param1,))
    else:
       cur.execute("SELECT * FROM people)
    return(cur.fetchall())

print(query_db(param1="Moscow", param2="Yeltsin", param3=72))
print(query_db(param1="Moscow", param2="Yeltsin"))
print(query_db(param1="Moscow"))
```

There are obvious issues with that: it does not work if param1 is None and it does not feel very intuitive. I could solve the problem with more if-loops and make it work with any of the three parameters, but that can't really be the way to do it, can it?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look this approach

```
def query_db(param1='', param2='', param3=''):
con = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
cur = con.cursor()

params = ()
query = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE 1=1 "
if param1:
    query += " AND city == ? "
    params += param1

if param2:
    query += " AND name == ? "
    params += param2

if param3:
    query += " AND age == ? "
    params += param3

cur.execute(query, params)

return(cur.fetchall())
```